# Entity Framework Power Tools: error "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

Short and sweet:

When I right click on my DBContext class and select "View Entity Data Model (read only)" I get a popup dialog box reading "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object", this is not showing up as an exception or output error when I compile and run my code normally; In fact, it seems like the relations and classes are working fine when I query the database from a console app I'm testing everything in.

Does anyone know why I'd be getting this error? Additionally, are there any tools to help validate my data mode? I occasionally get errors that point me to flaws, but more often then not I have to run a query to test things out. Any advice is appreciated!

Longer version:

I've been working on switching an EF database-first designer data-model to a code-first from existing database model. There are ~80 entities I've mapped to POCO classes, and defined at least as many relations using fluent API. I started from the scaffolded classes from running the visual studio wizard on the database, and that worked fine, but I've been doing a massive re-factoring to get the code base to work with the new models.

Anyway, I'm now testing the data-model by adding in one entity at a time so that I know which POCO entities and relations are causing trouble. I'd like to use EF power tools to help validate/visualize the model, but they are giving the error I described above. Again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: From my experience, if using the EF Power Tools and Database First, you should right click in the project, select EF submenu, then choose "Reverse Engineer". This will generate all the models you need and a DbContext.

Comment: That's what I did, as I said in the long explanation. However, there were problems with those models, both with interfacing with the ASP.NET app that uses them, and the relations between them. This is exacerbated by the fact that it's a legacy database with several vestigial components, and a general lacking of convention conformation.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, since SO won't let me edit my first comment.

EF power tools work if I run them in an empty solution/project that only contains the "reverse engineered" DbContext and models. Unfortunately, that process totally botched most of the relations, and property naming; so the model can't access the database.

Comment: If the database is "unconventional", you will need to fix the models and possibly use EF fluent API to configure said models. [EF Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

Comment: As I said in my question, I'm already doing that. But that's not what I'm looking for help with, I'm looking for ways to visualize/validate my model and EF power tools isn't working! Regardless, I appreciate the guidance you offered, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This post pointed me in the right direction](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/entity-framework-power-tool-tips-to-view-model-a-feature-i-depend-on/#comment-61793)

EF Power Tools is touchy about connection strings.  In my case I found that HOW the conn string is referenced in the DbContext class made a difference:

```
    internal class MyContext : DbContext
    {
    //Both Migrations and EF PowerTools were okay with this…
    public MyContext() : base(“name=MyConnStringName”)

    //Migrations was okay with this, but EF PowerTools Throws “object reference not set to an instance of an object” in a dialog box… Very confusing :s
    public MyContext() : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[“MyConnStringName”].ConnectionString)
```